# SQL or function

Tags: sql

In SQl its common to take the SUM of all values from a column

```
SELECT SUM(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```

Can the same thing be done but instead of summing each value in an attribute, each value is "OR'd" together? This would only work if the attribute was boolean of course

Comment: "*each value is "OR'd" together*" What would the result of this hypothetical function look like, exactly? Can you edit your question to provide a bit more background on what is driving this requirement?

Comment: OR-ing all boolean values in a column is equivalent to finding a single `true` value: if it's there, the `OR` will be true; if it's not there, the `OR` is going to be false. You don't need to go through all rows, either: as soon as you get the first `true`, you are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MAX(booleancolumn)` will return OR'd together. (Since `TRUE` > `FALSE`.)

Note that this will not work if null values are involved, because FALSE OR NULL evaluates to NULL.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two challenges here:

1. SQL doesn't have boolean type
2. This isn't part of any of the built-in aggregate functions.

However, some databases will allow you to define your own functions, including [aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-aggregate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). So it is at least possible.

Comment: SQL do have a boolean data type. And it can be used in MAX, MIN and COUNT aggregate functions.

Comment: @jarlh some dialects might (oracle, for example) but it's actually not part of the standard. Neither SQL Server nor MySql nor sqlite support it (Sql Server does have a `bit` type, but it's semantically very different and 1/0 don't translate to true/false in ways you'll always expect).

Comment: It's been ANSI/ISO SQL for ages. Check ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E), section 6.1 <data type>. (Since SQL-99.)